# Foundation 6 catch drilldown click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to catch the event of Foundation's 6 Drilldown.
I used a simple `on()` method with jQuery which doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).foundation();

$("body").on("click",".is-drilldown-submenu-parent",function(){
  alert("!");
})
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/Nirtz89/pen/jGExPd
Any ideas as to why it happens?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet inspect element, it is created after the initial code with `$(document).foundation();`

Comment: Your codepen works. It alerts `!` when you click on the items that have the class. What Do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Take a look at the drilldown items, they have a class of `is-drilldown-submenu-parent` but are not responding to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is already catched by foundation so you coulf try overriding it inserting a `off()` before the `on()` like

```
$(document).off().on("click",".is-drilldown-submenu-parent",function(){
  alert("!");
})
```